# Adding document with missing sequence date in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

Here see this [Collection here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51gU4.png) have a record with **createdAt** with *14Feb* and one with *16Feb*, Now querying an aggregation on the collection such as I want to add an document of **15Feb** as it was missing in collection with **viewCount** and **clickCount** as 0.

So looking for some way to add missing date record/document in aggreagation pipeline.

### Pipeline I have

````
          [
            {
              $group: {
                _id: {
                  $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$createdAt" },
                },
                viewCount: { $sum: "$viewCount" },
                clickCount: { $sum: "$clickCount" },
              },
            },
            { $sort: { _id: 1 } },
            {
              $group: {
                _id: null,
                data: {
                  $push: {
                    k: "$_id",
                    v: { viewCount: "$viewCount", clickCount: "$clickCount" },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              $project: {
                _id: 0,
                data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" },
              },
            },
          ]```

I looking for some operator in mongo or some way to do this
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combination of both javascript and aggregation pipeline, you can achieve the desired result.

```
// let's say datesArray has all the dates which are required. 
const datesArray = getDates(formattedFromDate, formattedToDate);


// aggregation pipeLine
    const pipeLine = [
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          date: '$date',
          viewCount: '$viewCount',
          clickCount: '$clickCount',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: datesArray,
          in: {
            k: '$$this',
            v: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $in: ['$$this', '$data.date'],
                },
                {
                  viewCount: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      '$data.viewCount',
                      {
                        $indexOfArray: ['$data.date', '$$this'],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                  clickCount: {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      '$data.clickCount',
                      {
                        $indexOfArray: ['$data.date', '$$this'],
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                {
                  viewCount: 0,
                  clickCount: 0,
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$densify`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/) and [`$fill`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/fill/) stages to fill gaps in your data. As a sample, I have changed your pipeline to not group by strings, but use `$dateTrunc` to cut of the dates after the day, so all you can group by day but still use an `ISODate` for easier interpolation afterwards.

Please note that this sample pipeline does only contain the first of the stages of your pipeline and can serve as a starting point. In order to show how you can fill in missing values, I have stopped at this point:

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateTrunc: {
          date: "$createdAt",
          unit: "day"
        }
      },
      viewCount: {
        $sum: "$viewCount"
      },
      clickCount: {
        $sum: "$clickCount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $densify: {
      field: "_id",
      range: {
        step: 1,
        bounds: "full",
        unit: "day"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $fill: {
      output: {
        viewCount: {
          value: 0
        },
        clickCount: {
          value: 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Use this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dThmClJMjZe) to test.

Comment: But there is a problem when I am fetching for more than a month when dates are repeated.
I want to get a document for each different day of the month for every month

Thank you for your efforts